# Is it possible to manipulate the html output of a control on a page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string, user-controls

I have a control on a page that does what it needs to do to work out what html it will render.

I want to manipulate this string right before it's rendered on the page.

**What I've Tried**

I'm assuming this need to be done on the Render event of the page. So I've overridden that and I'm attempting to use RenderControl. But I don't know where to go from here really.

I've also tried wrapping literal tags around this server side control (which it obviously won't allow) in order to access the Text property of the literal.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are trying to override the behavior of an existing control, you can a [Control adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx).

   Basically you override the native render of any control using this technique.

   In your case, you may use the native render method of the control to render to a `StringWriter`, process the restulting string and write back the string to the output.
2. If you have control on the source of the control, you can simply overwrite the various RenderX methods...

**[Edit]** Some kind of sample code (from memory, not sure about the syntax)

```
public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer){
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using(var sw = new StringWriter(sb)){
        this.RenderControl(sw);
    }

    var htmlResult = sb.ToString();

    var patchedHtml = DoSomething(htmlResult);

    writer.Writer(patchedHtml);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Steve. I think I'm trying to pursue the 2nd half of your first suggestion. +1.

Comment: I've now managed to successfully retrieve the html using StringWriter, how do I now 'inject' this back onto the page in place of the original html?